# Protractor: Invalid locator error with isElementPresent

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing, protractor

I have the following simple line of code in my e2e test...

```
var promise = ptor.isElementPresent(element(by.binding('firstName')));
```

I get an error that says `TypeError: Invalid locator`.  I don't see many other people getting this error after googling it.  Where did I make an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the syntax is(remove `element(...)`...

```
var promise = ptor.isElementPresent(by.binding('firstName'));
```